# Ubuntu OS failed after restarting

Tags: boot, bootloader

I'm running Ubuntu 18.4. The OS raid was created during the OS installation with (sdb1 & sc1)  file type ( NON-fs data) & I don't have any problem in this scenario> Then I had an sdb1 fault, so I replaced it with the drive, added to the RAID ( sudo mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1) after partition created. When I checked the status via ( sudo fdisk -l ), I got an sdb1 file system type (Linux) & no flag under the boot. (see attached) https://i.stack.imgur.com/6frez.jpg
also, I don't have any issues after restarting. My issue presented after I had sdc1 faulty, replaced with the new drive, and added to RAID  ( sudo mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1) I got an sdc1 file system type (Linux) & no flag under the boot, but after restarting, I couldn't boot from both of them ( new drives). When I reinsert the faulty drive I can boot. Please advise how to add them as boot devices.

Comment: Grub does not use boot flag. Windows uses boot flag and a few BIOS need to see a boot flag to work. But if booting in BIOS mode, you need grub installed to MBR. Not sure with RAID how you do that.

Comment: Should I change anything here? /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=0

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden

GRUB_TIMEOUT=0

GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: Post text in question, so you can maintain formatting. Difficult to read, but that looks like standard grub.